# How to call a class:method determined at runtime in perl?

Tags: perl, class, inheritance, oop

I am trying to make a crm application with a lot of crud actions. So I have controller classes like

```
CRM::Cities
CRM::Countries
```

No I use ORLite as a lite weight ORM. It creates -on the fly- classes like so

```
Model::Cities
Model::Countries
```

Now say I want to load a city. In the CRM::Cities class I have to do something like 
(ORLite uses class methods for access)

```
$obj1 = Model::Cities->load($id);
```

To load the current country in CRM::Countries:

```
$obj1 = Model::Countries->load($id);
```

So I end up in each controller class to enclose similar lines.

What I would want to be able todo is to do something generic like this in the CRM package (the base controller class):

```
$obj1 = Model::$package->load($id);
# package contains Cities or Countries, determined at runtime
```

I tried with various variations , with eval and so on but this is higher order perl. I think b/c the ORLite methods are class methods, inheritance is less obvious. Can someone give advice?  tia !

Answer (score 4):

Just put the whole package name, e.g. `Model::Cities`, into the variable. For example:

```
package Stuff::Yeah;

sub whatever {
  print "yes\n";
}

package main;

my $package = "Stuff::Yeah";
$package->whatever;
```

Comment: Or use quotes: `"Model::$package"->load($id);`

Answer (score 0):

```
die unless $package =~ /\A\w+\Z/;
eval "require Model::$package" or die $@;
$obj1 = "Model::$package"->load($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl lets you use strings as class names, so you can say

```
$obj1 = "Model::Cities"->load($id);
```

or indeed

```
$obj1 = "Model::$package"->load($id);
```

and in fact

```
my ($package) = $class =~ /([^:]+)$/;
$obj1 = "Model::$package"->load($id);
```

.

That's a nice generic way to load things, but I recommend one more layer of abstraction, to avoid getting too married to the one-Model-per-CRM-package idea:

```
sub _model_class {
    my ($class) = @_;

    my ($package) = $class =~ /([^:]+)$/;
    return "Model::$package";
}
```

And then

```
$obj1 = $class->_model_class->load($id);
```

.  This way, if one of the inheriting classes develops its own idea about what its model class ought to be (and this happens), you don't need to change any code.